# Is it ok to use BCrypt's generate_salt method to create a token for password resetting in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm creating a `password_reset` feature in rails the same way I did it when I used codeigniter.

For a user to reset their password, they type in their email address and click a button. The token is generated and stored in the database, and an email is sent to their email address with a URL containing that token.

When user clicks the link in the email, a method is called that checks that the token in their email matches the token stored in the db.

Now my question is: is it ok to use BCrypt's `generate_salt` method to generate this token, or is there some other way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SecureRandom.hex`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-hex) is more suitable in that case.

Answer (score 0):

since the modern encrption mechanism like shai doesnt allow decryption of the currrent passwords it is mandatory one to generate a new password. bcrypt should be fine doing this